# local storage errors in ts file. Terminal saying Invalid Character

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

It doesn't seem like there should be a problem setting and getting local storage varibales in a TS file but in each place in my code I call to local storage the terminal is giving me an "Invalid Character" error.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController, ModalController, NavController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { getPostsService } from '../../services/getPosts.service';
import { changeDefaultCity } from '../../services/changeDefaultCity.service';



@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [getPostsService, changeDefaultCity] 
})

export class Home {

    listOfEvents: Array<any> = []; 
    selectedCity: string; 
    defaultCity: string; 



    constructor (   public navCtrl: NavController,
                                public modalCtrl: ModalController,
                                public loading: LoadingController,
                                public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
                                public getPostSrvc: getPostsService, 
                                public chngDfCity: changeDefaultCity) {

        this.listOfEvents = [];
        let that = this;

/*If there's no selected city and this is a first load then default city needs to be set */

                        if(!this.defaultCity){

                              this.showCitySelector();

                              } else {
//default city already set so grab it from local storage 


/*THIS IS WHERE THE TERMINAL HAS A PROBLEM*/ 

            this.defaultCity = localStorage.getItem(“DefaultCity”);

                            //call service, get posts for this city
                                    this.getPostSrvc.getPosts(this.defaultCity,
                                function getPostsSuccess (listOfEventsObject) {
                                    for (var i in listOfEventsObject) {
                                        that.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[i]);
                                    }

                                },
                                function getPostsFailure (error) {


            }); 

                              }//close else statement


} // end of constructor

/* when new city selected from list call showCitySelector */

    showCitySelector() {

              let that = this;

        //ChangeCityFunction is the callback function for the popOver that shows the list of cities. 

                let changeCityFunction = function (changedNewCity) { 

                                            citySelectorPopOver.dismiss();

                                //make sure no default city set

                                            if(!that.defaultCity){

//TERMINAL GIVING SAME INVALID CHARACTER ERROR HERE 
                         localStorage.setItem("DefaultCity", changedNewCity);



                                            }
                                            that.selectedCity = changedNewCity;
                                            that.listOfEvents = [];

                                // call service again here. Same code from above            


                }; // end changeCityFunction


        let citySelectorPopOver =
                    this.popoverCtrl.create(
                        CitySelector,
                        {
                            callbackFunction: changeCityFunction
                        });
        citySelectorPopOver.present();

    } // end showCitySelector
```

Comment: “DefaultCity” looks strange, it should be "" instead of  “”.

Comment: It means the quotation marks look different in this call `this.defaultCity = localStorage.getItem(“DefaultCity”);`

Comment: I tried single quotes and that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.defaultCity = localStorage.getItem(“DefaultCity”);
```

The quotation marks in that line, `“”` looks strange, try changing them to regular quotation marks, `""` or `''`.